# Thymeleaf: Refresh value with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code in a Thymeleaf template.

```
 <div class="alert_counter" th:classappend="${numDeviceEventsWithAlarm>0} ?  show_info">
                                    <span th:text="${numDeviceEventsWithAlarm}">${numDeviceEventsWithAlarm}</span>
                                </div>
```

Is it possible to refresh the value `numDeviceEventsWithAlarm` using Ajax and without F5 ??

Comment: Thymeleaf renders your HTML page on server side and has no role after content is generated. If you want to use Ajax to update something on the web page, you can do it with Javascript / jQuery.

Comment: As @KedarJoshi stated and as mentioned on the [thymeleaf homepage](https://www.thymeleaf.org/): _"Thymeleaf is a modern **server-side** Java template engine for both web and standalone environments."_. So the answer is no, you can't change the `${numDeviceEventsWithAlarm}` variable but give the enclosing `span` an ID, change the contents of the span later-on using pure JS or a JS library of your choice.

Comment: The question was about Ajax only, not sure how relevant above JS advices are !!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the feature to only render a fragment of the Thymeleaf view.

First give the snippet of markup you want to update an *id*:

```xml
<span id="eventCount" th:text="${numDeviceEventsWithAlarm}"></span>
```

Then we can create a Spring request mapping in controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/event-count", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEventCount(ModelMap map) {
    // TODO: retrieve the new value here so you can add it to model map
    map.addAttribute("numDeviceEventsWithAlarm", count);

    // change "myview" to the name of your view 
    return "myview :: #eventCount";
}
```

See [Specifying fragments in controller return values](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#specifying-fragments-in-controller-return-values) in Thymeleaf manual to better understand the return that specifies which fragment to render.

Make a JavaScript function to update the value with [ajax (jQuery style)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```javascript
function updateEventCount() {
    $.get("event-count").done(function(fragment) { // get from controller
        $("#eventCount").replaceWith(fragment); // update snippet of page
    });
}
```

Then just call this function when you need to update the value.

Comment: Hi! Could you explain what is ".done(function(fragment) { // get from controller" ? Im confused. Am I supposed to replace function(fragment) with something?

Comment: @SHASHA  .done(function(fragment) { // get from controller" ? Im confused. Am I supposed to replace function(fragment)      is the ajax call to your endpoint /event-count

Comment: That works, but how to prevent replaceWith removing existing events on elements?

Comment: Thanks a ton friend, worked like a charm!!, brilliant trick. This is going to add a lot of dynamism to my pages.