# How to update the tymeleaf table in spring boot

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

After sending list data from rest controller to Ajax,
Is there a way to update the tymeleaf table in Ajax?

At first, I just wrote
return html::#id in the controller
and using #id.replace.with(data), but it has to be processed in the rest controller.

The append method is too complex and long.

```
 <tr th:each="fruit : ${fruits}">
      <td th:text="${fruit.cd}">/td>
      <td th:text="${fruit.name}">/td>
      <td th:text="${fruit.color}"></td>
    </tr>
```

Is there a way to update the tymeleaf data using ajax result?

Comment: have a look here: [thymeleaf-refresh-value-with-ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891551/thymeleaf-refresh-value-with-ajax)

Comment: This method was used by the controller but was not available by the rest controller.
Is there any other way to update the table in the script?

Comment: nope, as `${fruits},...` is not available on the client side.

Comment: add fragment-loading in your controller-class instead of your rest-controller class

Comment: I'd love to do it on the controller side, but... My boss told me to take care of it at rest controller. Is there only a way to use empty and attach it as append?